# Ruby tty prompt multiple choice to string

Tags: ruby, tty

```html
Game.rb

class Game

  attr_reader :name,:total_score,:top_scores

  def initialize
     @maingame = Story.new
   
  end

  def self.instructions

    font = TTY::Font.new(:doom)

  #puts font.write ("MIRKWOOD")
  #artii 'MIRKWOO'
  
  end

  prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

  font = TTY::Font.new(:doom)

#   name = prompt.ask 
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "                                                                                                         "


  puts ""
  puts "Welcome to Mirkwood".center(80)
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "This is a text based role playing game in the style of the old Choose Your Own Adventure books set in Tolkien's Middle Earth.".center(80)
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "At the end of a body of text from the story you will be presented with choices which will determine the path the story takes.".center(80)
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "                                                                                                         "

  prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

  font = TTY::Font.new(:doom)

#   name = prompt.ask 
  
  
  name = prompt.ask("Before you enter the Mirkwood adventurer do tell me your name?", default: "hero") do |q|
    q.required true
    q.validate /\A\w+\Z/
    q.modify   :capitalize


  end



  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "Your cloak flicks widly behind you, wrenched back and forth by an ill and cold"
  puts "wind bringing the smell of dank and decay from the dark forest ahead stretching"
  puts "as far as can be seen north, south and west."
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "To the southern side of the road sits a rickety old log cabin, there upon the front landing sits"
  puts "a withered old man whose eyes are covered by a strip of cloth belying the blindness beneath."
  puts "                                                                                                          "

  puts "Greetings #{name} I have been expecting you! Many have passed this way and so few have"
  puts "returned from the cursed Mirkwood, those that have rarely do speak of what lies within"
  puts "or beyond that dark place. You are either very brave or very motivated to enter here."
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts "                                                                                                         "

  puts "The road forks here brave #{name} and which of these three roads into the Mirkwood you take"
  puts "will be the first of many choices you must make on your journey."
  puts "                                                                                                         "
  puts " "
  

end

  
  
  #instructions

  prompt = TTY::Prompt.new

  

  choices1 = {The_north_road: 1, The_middle_road: 2, The_south_road: 3}
  choice = prompt.select("Which road do you choose?", choices1)

  

def
     next_fork = item.paragraph1 if choice == 1
     next_fork = item.paragraph2 if choice == 2
     next_fork = item.paragraph3 if choice == 3
     item = @maingame.get_fork(next_fork)
end
```

```html
Fork.rb

require_relative 'story'

class Fork

    attr_reader :id, :story, :path1, :path2, :finish, :score
  
    def initialize(id,story,paragraph1,paragraph2,paragraph3,paragraph4,paragraph5,finish,score)
      @id = id
      @story = story
      @paragraph1 = paragraph1
      @paragraph2 = paragraph2
      @paragraph3 = paragraph3
      @paragraph4 = paragraph4
      @paragraph5 = paragraph5
      @finish = finish
      @score = score
    end
  
  end
```

```html
Story.rb

class Paragraph1 

 attr_accessor    :id , :description

    

paragraph1 = puts"Ah the north road, a wise choice friend as your way will meander towards Ered Mithrin and Durins folk of the Grey Mountains'
'Perhaps like Gandalf and his companions who whence this way you will find Erebor the lonely mountain, whereby Smaug the Terrible met his end.'
'Now friend the hour grows late and you best away lest you not find a clearing within the woods to light a fire for camp at night.
'Bidding the kind old man well and flicking a silver coin his
```

I am trying to build a simple choose your own adventure based terminal app with Ruby.

I am using tty prompt to post the questions and give options-

```rb
    puts "The road forks here brave #{name} and which of these three roads into the Mirkwood you take"
      puts "will be the first of many choices you must make on your journey."
      puts " "                                                                                                    
      puts " "
      
    end
    
      prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
    
      choices1 = {The_north_road: 1, The_middle_road: 2, The_south_road: 3}
      choice = prompt.select("Which road do you choose?", choices1)
```

I would like to choices to lead to a string depending on the choice, with the strings stored in another ruby file. However, this does not seem to work. Choices lead to an unexpected input.

Error =game.rb:117: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' or '\n' next_fork = item.paragraph1 if choice == 1 –

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Tip: There's no need for this throw-away variable `choices1`. Just add those arguments to your `select()` call directly.

Comment: Can you show the code that generated the error and include the error itself.

Comment: Could you add to the question the specific error and the code is generating it? because, from I can see, there's no error in the code you've added.

Comment: Error =game.rb:117: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' or '\n'
     next_fork = item.paragraph1 if choice == 1

Comment: Tip: In Ruby use *varargs* as in `def initialize(id, story, *paragraphs)` If you need additional arguments and you're using Ruby 3 consider [keyword arguments](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/) as well. It's also not uncommon to send in hash options.

Comment: You have a spurious `def` before that line for no apparent reason.

Comment: Although we ask for code here, there's usually no need to post 100+ lines of code. Try to shorten your code by removing all parts that aren't relevant to your problem.

Comment: The game.rb that you posted only has 100 lines, but your error is on line 117. Maybe just grap lines 110 to 120 and post them in your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted refers to game.rb:117. Line 117 in your game.rb file. The game.rb you added to the question only has 100 lines, but I assume you removed some code from it before posting. If you go to line 117 in your game.rb file you'll find this:

```
def
  next_fork = item.paragraph1 if choice == 1
  next_fork = item.paragraph2 if choice == 2
```

In ruby the keyword `def` defines a method, but it also requires a name. Ruby assumes that `next_fork` is the name of the method because that's the first thing after the `def`. After that there is a `=` which cannot appear just after a method definition and is a syntax error. This is what ruby is telling you.

```
game.rb:117: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' or '\n' next_fork = item.paragraph1 if choice == 1
```

Give a name to the method.